# How to allow only 2 selection checkbox in a form with?

Tags: php, javascript

I want to put a form on my website for giving away 3 prizes. Each member to be able to select only 2 item on the list that they wish to win.

I have created the form and with JavaScript it works fine, but it's client side and can't be trusted.

What is the best way to implement such thing and be sure that each user can ONLY select 2 item? best way to do it with PHP?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Best scenario: 1) select item, 2) send value to server, 3) server checks, and 4) gives the result back.

Comment: Well this is what radio buttons are for, not checkboxes.  By using checkboxes for this, you are presenting an inconsistent experience in the UI to your users.

Comment: @StefanH that's right, to be honest I haven't decided yet if I should allow one selection or more, therefor I want to go with the checkbox and figure it out if I decide to use 2 checkboxes.  Let's say I want to have 2 selections and the form has more than that.

Comment: @VisioN do you have any code example for such solution?

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you use radiobuttons?

```
<form method="post">
     Price 1 <input type="radio" value="price 1" />
     Price 2 <input type="radio" value="price 2" />
     Price 3 <input type="radio" value="price 3" />
</form>
```

And if you want to allow multiple prizes just switch to checkboxes

```
<form method="post">
     Price 1 <input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="price 1" />
     Price 2 <input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="price 2" />
     Price 3 <input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="price 3" />
</form>
```

Comment: He wants the user to be able to pick 2 prices!

Comment: he edited his question, his first question was to pick only one price

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is boss, have a look here.

http://gravitywiz.com/2012/06/11/limiting-how-many-checkboxes-can-be-checked/

Comment: yeah and what if javascript is disabled?

Comment: @Drew Rush, Thank you, but its still a client side solution.

Comment: Do you want to check the form before submission? Or do you care if it hits the server and returns an error?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
Price 1<input value="price1" type="checkbox" name="price[]">
Price 2<input value="price2" type="checkbox" value="price[]">
Price 3<input value="price3" type="checkbox" value="price[]">
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Then check the size of the array `$_POST['price']`:

```
<? 
   if(isset($_POST['send'])) {
       if(sizeof($_POST['price']) == 2) {
           //here you go
       } else { 
          echo "error, pick exactly two prices!";
       } 
   }

?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I got some errors and fixed it. It looks like it's working :)`<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
if(sizeof($_POST['price']) == 2){
echo "OK"; 
}
else{
echo "NOT OK"; 
}
  }
?>
<form action="check.php" method="post" id="check">
Price 1<input value="price1" type="checkbox" name="price[]">
Price 1<input value="price2" type="checkbox" name="price[]">
Price 1<input value="price3" type="checkbox" name="price[]">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>`